# how to set user agent in rspec route assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to use rails-rpec route specs to test different routing based on different user agents, and I cannot find the correct method or object to stub.

My method looks like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "articles routing" do
  describe "/articles/#slug" do

    it "routes to Articles#show" do
      get("/articles/fancy-slug").should route_to(controller: "articles",
                                                    action:     "show",
                                                    id:         "fancy-slug")
    end

    describe "when you have an iphone user agent" do
      before(:each) do
        # SOMETHING MAGICAL HAPPENS ALONG THE LINES OF THE LINE BELOW
        # request.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"
      end

      it "routes to Mobile::Articles#show" do
        expect(get: "/articles/fancy-slug").to route_to(controller: "mobile_articles",
                                                      action:     "show",
                                                      id:         "fancy-slug")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to stub the request, or the controller, or the whatever. Most of the available documentation seems to refer to an old/outdated version of the `get` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work, but here's something to try:

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/matchers/routing_matchers.rb) for the `RouteToMatcher`, it just parses a controller/action pair (given as a hash or in `controller#action` format) and any other parameters given along with them and then delegates to [`ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions#assert_recognizes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a779ea9d57b00bd3b59f5546603271c2d302247c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb#L40). But that method builds the `request` object from the parameters you pass in as the argument to `route_to`. So there's no easy way to access the request object from your spec. However, to build this dummy request,
it calls

`ActionController::TestRequest.new`

So you might try

```
ActionController::TestRequest.any_instance.stub(:user_agent).
  and_return "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"
```

Comment: That's very close! What I got working was:`ActionDispatch::Request.any_instance.stubs(:user_agent).returns("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25")`

Comment: Awesome! That syntax looks a bit unfamiliar to me; do you mind if I ask which version of rspec you're using?

Comment: I stub using mocha, which has a slightly different syntax.